# How to add a custom web part to a master page using SharePoint Designer?

Tags: sharepoint-online, master-page

I want to add my custom web part in master page using SharePoint Designer.

I tried but I am receiving the error shown below.

[image]

And this is the description of error.

> ExecuteRequestInSandBox call failed. System.NullReferenceException:
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.BinaryWebPartSerializer.Serialize(PersonalizationScope
>   scope, BinaryWebPartSerializerFlag binaryWebPartSerializerFlags,
>   BinaryWebPartSerializerWriter writer)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.BinaryWebPartSerializer.Serialize(SerializationMode
>   mode, BinaryWebPartSerializerFlag binaryWebPartSerializerFlags,
>   BinaryWebPartSerializerWriter writer)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPUserCodeWebPart.EnsurePersistedBlobsMatchPropertiesCollection()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPUserCodeWebPart.GetWebPartDataForRemoteCall(Object&
>   viewState, Object& controlState)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeWebPartRemoteExecutionHelper.ExecuteRequestInSandBox(HttpContext
>   context, SPWeb web, SPWebPartManager manager, SPUserCodeWebPart
>   userCodeWebPart)

[image]

Comment: What/how did you try to add your custom web part?

Comment: How did you added web part in master page? Can you provide some code ?

Comment: http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Forum/Details/how-to-add-custom-webpart-to-master-page-using-sharepoint-607.aspx

Comment: i followed the link mension to add as above for adding web part to master page,and i also tried same with the designer option using browser where we are using snippet section to get html of web part to place in html page associated to a master page like seattle.html and seattle.master where added the code web part in.html page but there also it shows the same error

Comment: Try this: http://ukreddysharepoint2010.blogspot.in/2014/05/how-to-add-web-part-to-master-page-in.html

Comment: tahnks ,but i have already tried this way too but it also give me the same error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get full qualified assembly of SharePoint solution from visual studio using following steps:

```
Open Visual Studio
Go to Tools –> External Tools –> Add
    Title: Get Qualified Assembly Name
    Command: Powershell.exe
    Arguments: -command "[System.Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName(\"$(TargetPath)\").FullName"
    Check "Use Output Window".
```

Register webpart in master page like:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WpNs" Namespace="SPDemo.NewWebpart" Assembly="SPDemo, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2c5bae03c7cf380a"%>
```

Add webpart where you want to add like:

```
<WpNs:NewWebpart ID="testid" runat="server"></WpNs:NewWebpart>
```

It will work

Comment: Thank You so much for your kind reply, the article i have followed i.e  http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Forum/Details/how-to-add-custom-webpart-to-master-page-using-sharepoint-607.aspx  this article also tells the same way as you mentiond,but  still i followed your steps as you said but no change in result.

Comment: Yes, you have done that. But deploy solution globally and verify your fully qualified assembly. Before few days, i have already done this.It's worked perfectly. That's why i am replying you again.

Comment: my bad luck ,it's not working.but thank you Viraj

Comment: Welcome. Can you post here your registration code line and webpart line?

Comment: this is the registration line <%@ Register TagPrefix="WpNs0" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

Comment: and i tried to share web part code too but due to character limits am enable to do that,but i have an added these details in question please kindly review that once

Comment: You are passing wrong assembly and namespace. Have you develop your webpart in visual studio? If yes, follow above steps and get proper assembly of your solution.

Comment: Try this, but once verify publickeyToken

<%@ Register TagPrefix="WpNs" Namespace="SharePointProject10.SPUserCodeWerbPart" Assembly="SharePointProject10, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2c6a7odb391b6c65"%>



<WpNs:SPUserCodeWerbPart ID="testid" runat="server"></WpNs:SPUserCodeWerbPart>

Comment: but now i am start getting error at web part code because now it is generating code for web part like---<WpNs1:WebPart1 runat="server" ....></WpNs1:WebPart1> and afte running page its showing error at this web part tag

Comment: Ok good. Now you are nearer about your solution. Have you deploy solution globally? check it. Add above two lines which i have set exactly according to your code.

Comment: yes the wsp is globally deployed,and i am directly exporting my web part page and then i am simply copy that web part and registration code and pasting that in master page. but now its showing Unknown server tag 'SharePoint:SPHtmlTag'. error

Comment: <%@ Register TagPrefix="WpNs" Namespace="SharePointProject10.SPUserCodeWerbPart" Assembly="SharePointProject10, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2c6a7odb391b6c65"%> 


<WpNs:SPUserCodeWerbPart ID="testid" runat="server"></WpNs:SPUserCodeWerbPart>

No need to add webpart page code in master page. Please remove it

Comment: still its showing the same error

Comment: <%@ Register TagPrefix="WpNs1" Namespace="SharePointProject11.WebParts.WebPart1" Assembly="SharePointProject11, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fad3ae7442a78644"%>

Comment: <WpNs1:WebPart1 runat="server" ID="g_b966e189_07c9_4878_85d6_d103ce556992"></WpNs1:WebPart1>

Comment: WebParts is what? 

Replace SharePointProject11.WebParts.WebPart1 to SharePointProject11.WebPart1

Comment: webparts is a folder which contains the web parts in visual studio

Comment: nope,it's still showing same error after making chnges as u said

Comment: Thanks Viraj with your kind and great help i have added web part to master page.Thank you soooooooooo much

Comment: Welcome. If ans is helpful to you, mark it.

Comment: but this is limited to farm solution web parts isn't it??because the same one I tried for sandbox web part and it's not working there.

Comment: May be, it was not deploying globally or not getting publictokenkey.

Comment: so it is necessary  to deploy globally only??

Comment: May be, not sure. because i had worked only for farm.

Comment: actually,i tried that also means i deployed solution globally and tried to add web part to master page and unfortunately that didn't worked.