# Add custom webpart (app) to masterpage [O365, SPO]

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, master-page

I want to create webpart that will render content of selected termset, and I need to put this webpart on masterpage, instead of default navigation.

I found some solutions (like [this](http://ukreddysharepoint2010.blogspot.com/2014/05/how-to-add-web-part-to-master-page-in.html) and [that](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/175777/how-to-add-a-custom-web-part-to-a-master-page-using-sharepoint-designer#)), but both goes with SP2013.
Is there any way to do the same with app in SPO?

Comment: It is not advised to mess with the Master Page on an Online SharePoint.  Any changes outside the original template has a good chance of trying to force back to default when updates are run.    I would make a page for it and link it in your navigation.  This way it will be across your sites.

Comment: @lazoDev thank you for your answer. Can you explain it a little more, I'm not sure that I understand this 'make a page for it and link it in your navigation'-thing

Comment: Create a normal page in SharePoint and build your web part there.  You are going to be limited to client interaction with the Online SharePoint.  You can get your taxonomy with CSOM, JSOM and REST.  Then, just put that page into your navigation for the site.